# Monitor Busy Box NTPD in Tiny Core Linux

Tags: busybox, ntpd, tinycore

I use Busy Box with Tiny Core Linux in a virtual appliance. I can run NTP Daemon using

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd -p pool.ntp.org
```

The problem is it doesn't output any logs to /var/log/ntp.log. Am I looking at the wrong place for logs? What is the best way to confirm ntpd is running properly? (Currently, the only way I can confirm ntpd is running is verifying whether the process is running). I also tried using verbose option.

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd -d -p pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's best to use one of the NTP clients such as `ntpq` or `ntpstat` to query your local `ntpd` once it's been started to confirm it's working.

#### For example

*ntpq*

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.           5 l  35m   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 97-127-48-73.mp .STEP.          16 u   6d 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 F-Current.sjela 216.218.254.202  2 u  113  256  377   81.887  64016.5 1228.28
+ns522433.ip-158 18.26.4.105      2 u   12  256  377   37.641  62638.8 1168.32
*nu.binary.net   129.7.1.66       2 u  263  256  377   56.722  63177.5 731.976
```

*ntpstat*

```
$ ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (216.229.0.50) at stratum 3
   time correct to within 63367 ms
   polling server every 256 s
```

#### Busybox

According to this page titled: [External Tiny Utilities](https://busybox.net/tinyutils.html) there's additional clients that are BusyBox specific. There's one titled: `ntpclient`, according to that page.

- http://doolittle.icarus.com/ntpclient/

#### References

- [22.13. CHECKING THE STATUS OF NTP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-checking_the_status_of_ntp)
- https://busybox.net/tinyutils.html
- https://github.com/Telconet/ntpclient

Comment: Thanks. So do you recommand installing ntpq or ntpstat in Tiny Core? Because BusyBox does not come with any of those.

Comment: @user2481857 - I would try starting w/ `ntpq`. More here - https://busybox.net/tinyutils.html.

Comment: @user2481857 - I also found this guide - http://www.m-opensolutions.com/?p=343.